# How to retrieve all the groups that a user has from Azure AD in C# ASP.NET Core 6.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to get all the groups that an user has but I can't achieve that. Here's what I've been trying:

```
public async Task<string> traerGrupos(string userID)
{
            string currentUser = "null";

            try
            {
                var tenant = "mytenant";
                var clientID = "myclientid";
                var secret = "mysecretkey";
                var clientSecretCred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenant, clientID, secret);
                
                GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCred);

                var usr = graphClient.Users[userID.ToString()].Request()
                .Select(x => x.DisplayName).GetAsync().Result;

                currentUser = usr.DisplayName;
                return currentUser;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return currentUser = ex.Message;
            }
}
```

But I cannot see an option to get the groups. Besides, I get this error:

> Code: Authorization_RequestDenied Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
> Inner error: AdditionalData: date: 2022-12-06T19:54:23...

but my app has every permission that it requires.

How could I solve this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to check that you have an app registration in your AAD and have the admin consent for the scope of `User.Read.All` (GraphAPI) as an application permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your requirement can be done by [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

And I noticed that you are using Graph SDK, so your code should look like this:

```
var memberOf = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].MemberOf
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Then I noticed you are using client credential flow by this code `new ClientSecretCredential`, so I agree with Charles Han that you should set the scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

Then the whole progress is:

Adding correct API permission in Azure AD application for `Application` type `Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All`

[image]
[image]

Your code should look like this:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var memberOf = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();
```

[image]

Comment: Please note, this API will return groups, directory roles, and administrative units that the user is a direct member of. You need to identify if the response is a group, and pls see my test result screenshot, the value type `Microsoft.Graph.Group` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the scope set up correctly in the app registration, try to add the scope in your GraphServiceClient constructor,

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCred, scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have the correct credentials/rights for the graph API as Charles Han says.

Remember that you can try the [explorer the Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and read more in [the docs about](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) `transitiveMemberOf`

I would do/have done something like this

```cs
...
//{userPrincipalName} = email or id {GUID} of user
 var usersTentativeGroups = new List<ADTentativeGroup>();

            await SetAccessTokenInHeader();
            var url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/transitiveMemberOf";
            var jsonResp = await _client.GetAsync(url);

            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ADGroupRoot>(await jsonResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            AddResultIfNotNull(usersTentativeGroups, result);

            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result?.NextLink))
            {
                await SetAccessTokenInHeader();
                jsonResp = await _client.GetAsync(result.NextLink);
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ADGroupRoot>(await jsonResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                AddResultIfNotNull(usersTentativeGroups, result);
            }
```